# Python Dataframe comparing DateTime row values that are near to another and returning a new row

Tags: python

I have a pandas Dataframe in Python 2.7 (df, with a sample below:

PRODUCT CONTRACT TYPE   STRIKE  SETTLEMENT PRICE    EXPIRATION DATE
Brent Crude Futures C   98.5    0.01    2015-09-10
Brent Crude Futures C   99.0    0.01    2015-09-10
Brent Crude Futures F   NaN     47.58   2015-09-15
Brent Crude Futures P   100.0   52.43   2015-09-10
Brent Crude Futures P   101.0   53.43   2015-09-10
Brent Crude Futures P   101.5   53.93   2015-09-10

I would like to have that for every contract type (C,P,F) it finds the F with the EXPIRATION DATE nearest to the (C,P,F)'s date (but with an Expiration that is after, not before the date) to it's EXPIRATION DATE and fills the cell of a new column called "SPOT", with the SETTLEMENT PRICE of that F.  The output should be

PRODUCT CONTRACT TYPE   STRIKE  SETTLEMENT PRICE    EXPIRATION DATE  SPOT
Brent Crude Futures C   98.5    0.01    2015-09-10  47.58
Brent Crude Futures C   99.0    0.01    2015-09-10  47.58
Brent Crude Futures F   NaN     47.58   2015-09-15  47.58
Brent Crude Futures P   100.0   52.43   2015-09-10  47.58
Brent Crude Futures P   101.0   53.43   2015-09-10  47.58
Brent Crude Futures P   101.5   53.93   2015-09-10  47.58

The Dataframe itself is very large and has a lots of C,F,P's

Many thanks..

Comment: DId you try doing anyting by yourself? DO you have a specific problem?

Comment: of course I tried to do it first, for quite some time. one challenge appears to be that issue that you cannot, for instance, do a merge on nearby dates only exact matches.  I could try and use timedelta(days+k) and go through k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6 and try and write a boolean. but can't get a solution that works.